# Angular Material Input Text area allow only new inputs and disables edit or delete of current value

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a Text Area input for users in an application that lets them put down notes. this is shared between all users. Is there any way to make the input so that it only allows new inputs and not let users delete or modified the data that's already there to prevent them from modifying other users notes? I guess you can just disable input all together and just have a concat or something in the backend after the user submits but I would have to show the previous notes also. how would you make it seem like one text area? is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: how do you know when a user is finished entering in there data?

Comment: I wonder if you could take the previous entry string and make the text area have to "start with" the previous data

Comment: If the content needs to be kept, why do you put it in a text-area?

Comment: there's an update button that user clicks after the user is finished. this is a general notes section for a patient in a care facility. so multiple users will come and put in data. there should've been a notes table that links users sessions to each patient but at the time there wasn't this requirement. scope creep i guess. What should I put it in, if not a text-area? It's just a varchar in the SQL db.